# ASP.NET MVC Web API data annotation regular expression for email

Tags: regex, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

Using `[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$")]` attribute never validates an email property of my model. I'm new to regular expressions so I can't figure out what is the problem. Little help?

Comment: Could you provide an input that should match the regex? Are the emails *contained* in strings? For example, either `x@x.x` or `text before x@x.x text after`?

Comment: For example johndoe@gmail.com or john.doe@gmail.com should pass.

Comment: [MVC Email Regular Expression C#](http://lesson8.blogspot.com/2013/03/email-regular-expression-mvc-c.html)

Answer (score 9):

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Email Address")]
[EmailAddress]
public string email { get; set; }
```

Something like this should solve you problem.  The email validation has been build in 4.5 check out [this msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true)

Comment: This approach doesn't work with older browsers (which doesn't support input type of email). So you should provide RegularExpression attribute as a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the ModelState property for validation errors? Look at the example at the bottom of this page:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2012/06/28/error-handling-in-asp-net-webapi.aspx

for a way of sending back error messages to the client when validation fails.

Comment: Yes I have done that part. The problem is that email is never validated, even when it's in a correct form. This regex should validate johndoe@gmail.com, but it doesn't.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. If I try to send johndoe, I get "The field Email must match the regular expression '^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$'." as a model state error. So it looks like it's validating just fine.