# Regular Expression Validation in MVC 3, Visual Studio 2010, .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am using MVC3 for my web application, I have used regular expression to validate email adress.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid emailId.")]
```

It is not working at all. While I am updating record using LINQ, as below

```
                details.UserName = profile.UserName;
                details.Password = profile.Password;
                _context.SaveChanges();
```

Its giving an error which describes Nothing (You may be already familiar with it)

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

I got rid of it when I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400530/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-while-saving-changes-to-sql-server-da). Problem was due to Email was not validated properly, however my regular expression was valid. I googled and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612603/asp-net-mvc-web-api-data-annotation-regular-expression-for-email) and [this](https://gist.github.com/jbubriski/4198259) but problem was not yet resolved. Some good this happened when I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137719/how-to-create-regularexpressionattribute-with-dynamic-pattern-come-from-model-pr)., but still if you see above article, it has one line as

```
PropertyInfo property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(PatternProperty);
```

which return null and validation still fails. Could anyone help me out why MVC3 don't validate regular expressions as Javascript and suggest best solution to my problem?

*MODEL*

```
  public class SystemUserMetaData
    {
    [Mail]
        [MailAddress]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "invalid.")]
        //[DynamicReqularExpression(PatternProperty=@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string EmailId { get; set; }
    }
```

thanks.

Comment: [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid email address.")] 
Try this.

Comment: Tried and failed..!! because the way javascript validate and MVC validates doesn't seems to be unique. I already tried some RegEx which was working fine with javascript but not MVC.

Comment: Could you please share the actual code

Comment: What is the datatype that you are using for email field in db?

Comment: You already have an Email validator in data annotations. Are you trying to check for valid email id?

Comment: @Reddy I think if I use .NetFramework 4.0, there will be no Email validators in Data.Annotaion. Is there any way to use that??

Comment: Ensure Unobtrusive javascript validation is happening in your view.
Check the second answer in this..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430583/mvc-validation-regex-attribute-works-in-c-sharp-but-not-javascript

Comment: @Rifaj I am unable to search jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

Comment: You mentioned that the error is due to unobtrusive validation.
You are missing the email validation in your view. 
Check this article to enable unobtrusive validation.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/577937/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Validating-Model-Data-and
or else you need to have javascript validation on submit

Comment: @Rifaj I followed you but same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

`[Required(ErrorMessage = "E-mail must be entered")]
            [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]`

Comment: [EmailAddress] also not an atrribute :(

Comment: Have you added the `using` reference properly?

Comment: using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45874/discussion-between-reddy-and-imad)